# What's the UI design pattern for displaying content in a window when menu item is selected?

Tags: winforms

I am new to Windows Forms. I have a menu in a form. When a user selects a menu option I want to display some elements like a grid, treeview or a grouped UI elements.

What is the UI design pattern for displaying the view for the selected option? Load a user control dynamically in a pane? Show a form and hide a previous form? I am not using tab control. Content is displayed in a pane in the form. It's not a separate window.

I have searched high and low for sample applications and I couldn't find any which has a menu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Constructing your form as needed in designer and then hiding and showing sounds like a reasonable approach.

I definitely would avoid dynamic content loading. In WinForms you are most likely relying on events to handle UI interaction. If loading/unloading controls dynamically you would have to take care of hooking/unhooking event handlers. It's easy to keep track of that when you have 3 controls each with single event. But if you have more controls and each controls has to take care of many events the loading/unloading and hooking/unhooking events is going to be error prone. Also unhooked event handlers will result in memory leaks. Other problem is that your complex controls will have many properties. All of them will have to be set up in code. You will end up with dozens of lines listing controls' properties and assigning values to them.

Hiding/showing doesn't expose you to these issues. You design your layout once in the designer. So your main code is not clattered with pure UI construction. Also, you do not create a new instance of a control when you show it so you can subscribe event handlers to events at design time and you do not have to worry about unhooking the handlers when hiding. You create one instance of a control and rely on this instance throughout application lifetime.

Comment: Why do you think there needs to be event hooking and unhooking? You hook an event like clicked which does the same thing every time and it stays hooked.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich I only said there would be hooking/unhooking if you decide to create a control dynamically. I thought your idea with dynamic creation was that when you need e.g. a combobox you crate it. Then when you need a data grid, you remove the combobox and in its place you create the data grid. If you need a combobox again you create a new instance and so on. Sure you can create it and hide/show once it's created but then why not create it at design time since you need the logic for hide/show anyway. But if you create new instance without unhooking the old one won't be garbage collected.